# MYSQL where clause join a string search

Tags: mysql

Very hard for me to describe this, i'll show you want I am trying to to

albums_lookup has the structure

```
lookup    |    id
```

where lookup is in the format uid/title

My query

```
SELECT `id`
FROM
    `albums_lookup`
WHERE
    `lookup` = (SELECT 
            `id`
        FROM
            `users`
        WHERE
            `username` = 'someusername') + '/sometitle'
```

as you can tell, I have a username, I need to first to get id of the user, then append the text '/sometitle' in the where clause

Comment: So, why doesn't that work? What error do you get?

Comment: well that was a waste of time, I forgot to update the entry in the db, it works as intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `CONCAT` and a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT id
FROM albums_lookup al
INNER JOIN users u
   ON CONCAT(al.lookup, '/sometitle') = u.id
WHERE u.username = 'someusername';
```

Comment: may I ask, what is the difference between the two queries? Which would be the "proper" approach?

Comment: subqueries should typically be avoided, they aren't performant and as the table gets larger the performance will degrade rapidly

Comment: @Martin: OP sums `id` and a string

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `id`
FROM
`albums_lookup`
WHERE
`lookup` = concat_ws((SELECT 
        `id`
    FROM
        `users`
    WHERE
        `username` = 'someusername') ,'sometitle');
```